# On the asynchrony of Promises and how they achieve it

Tags: javascript, node.js

The first question I have is about Promises. The definition I tend to get about Promises is that they offer a synchronous solution to otherwise asynchronous events, which I understand in principle, but I have trouble with that notion since I know that the body within the Promise executes synchronously, so how would it be that code could just skip past a promise and not resolve it right then and there, as perhaps would be the case in the piece of code below? How does the interpreter make it to p2 after p1 synchronously without skipping?

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
(async () => {
const p1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const p2 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2');

console.log([await p1, await p2]);
})();
```

Secondly, how do functions like fetch or fs.readFile in particular achieve that asynchrony and leaving the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really big question.

In short, `fetch()` returns a `Promise` which represents a task that will finish at some point in the future. This object itself is synchronous. Promises can store functions that will execute *after* the task finishes through the use of `then`/`catch`. This is why you can chain `.then()` and execution order of the registered callbacks will be the order they are added in.

by default, the code does not "wait" for the promise to be finished; you just register continuations.

`async`/`await` are keywords that instruct the runtime to, in short, re-arrange the code in such a manner that the code that comes *after* the `await` is (sort of) added to a `then()` call back. I'm simplifying heavily, but essentially the JS runtime will re-arrange your code into this:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
(() => {
  const p1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  const p2 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2');
  p1.then(result => p2.then(result2 => [result, result2])).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
  });
})();
```

So, the reason why the runtime can continue is because `fetch()` does not wait for anything - it returns an object that will eventually be notified of when an asynchronous task will be completed. The `await` calls are just syntactic sugar that the runtime unfolds into `then`/`catch` etc.

The benefit of this is that the runtime will not actually wait for operations to finish until you call `await` - which allows you to kick off multiple long-running operations in parallel (as you do in this example) and then wait for them to be finished individually.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, especially with the .then chain. Does fetch use an event listener of some kind to get off the main thread to assign a task?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0):

Think of promises as delegation. The main process of javascript is a single process, running on a single cpu, so it's like a boss but a boss that can do work itself.

But the boss has people who work for him, and so when you see `const p1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');` basically imagine that as the boss giving the url to a worker, saying "get me the contents of this url while i do other things", so the worker goes off to get the contents of the url and leaves the boss with a `promise` that the boss can use to find out if and when the worker is done with his job.